# Incorrect Chinese number sort order on iOS using NSLocale zh_Hans_CN?

Tags: ios, sorting, chinese-locale

So I have an app where I want to sort data by arbitrary locales - not the phone locale.
It looks to me like the sort order iOS gives for chinese is wrong (but I don't know chinese) so can someone tell me if this is correct or not?

I believe that for both simplified/trad chinese, the numbers 1 to 10 are:

一 , 二 , 三 , 四 , 五 , 六 , 七 , 八 , 九 , 十

Here is my test code:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh_Hans_CN"];
NSArray *outOfOrder = @[@"十", @"七", @"一", @"二", @"四", @"三", @"五", @"六", @"八", @"九"];

NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
                                    {
                                        return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [(NSString *)obj1 length]) locale:locale];
                                    }];

NSArray *sorted = [outOfOrder sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDescriptor]];
```

But the sorted array comes out like this:
八,
二,
九,
六,
七,
三,
十,
四,
五,
一

Surely chinese should sort like other languages with the equivalent of 1..9 followed by the 'word' characters etc.?

Comment: Chinese and Japanese sort characters using radicals and strokes or a pronunciation transliteration (pinyin). Their meaning does not play a role. According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-SW1) if you want Finder like sorting pass `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSNumericSearch | NSWidthInsensitiveSearch | NSForcedOrderingSearch`. This will not change the sort order in your case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NSLocale to sort Chinese. iOS support [ICU alphabetic](http://site.icu-project.org/design/alphabetic-index).

Han collation support:

- Pinyin: A B C D ...
- Stroke: 1 2 3 ...
- Radical-Stroke: radicals

Here is some sample codes for your reference:

```
NSLocale* strokeSortingLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"zh@collation=stroke"];
NSComparator compareByStroke = ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [obj1 length]) locale:strokeSortingLocale];
};

NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name_ch" ascending:YES comparator:compareByStroke];
NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
NSArray* sortedArray = [self.result sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: So an English speaker would expect a mixed numbers/letters list to be ordered like this: 1 book street, 2 apple road, 5 tree road, apple lane, black ave, book st, zebra road. Would a Chinese user of an app, looking at a tableview list of street addresses, like the above but in Chinese, expect them ordered according to stroke? So the equivalent of 2 apple road might be half way down the list and not the second?

Comment: If you ordering by stroke, you will see the stroke order list then english alphabetical.

Comment: The question I asked in my comments was what would a Chinese user expect as a rule? Would they expect stroke sort order, therefore the characters for numbers don't appear at the top of the list? I think the answer to my original question is no, the sort order I saw is not wrong, but I'll accept your answer, thanks.